# Google Drive requires authentication despite public folder access

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

If a folder has a permission that allows anyone with the link the read, trying to download specific file from that folder using

```
https://googledrive.com/host/<<<folder_id>>>/<<<file_name>>>
```

will redirect to the Google service login page.

However if the folder has a permission that allows anyone to find it and read the file will be downloaded correctly without being redirected to the service login page.

Is this the intended behavior despite the UI claiming "... no login required"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is intended behavior. The URL you're trying to build is from Drive's hosting feature. That [requires using the "Public on the web" permission](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) to be accessible there.

Using the lesser permission, it is possible to download via the UI with the link from sharing.

If you're looking for programatic downloads, you can use the Drive API to download without authentication (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FILE_ID?alt=media&key=YOUR_KEY) although that requires at least an API key for the registered app.

**Update:**

Please note that the server only responds with the headers needed for CORS when a valid `origin` header is present (browsers normally include this, so don't typically need to do anything.) For example:

```
curl -vv 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FILE_ID_HERE?key=YOUR_API_KEY&alt=media' > out.tmp
```

The above request will not yield `access-control-*` headers. Including an `origin` header as a browser would does:

```
curl -H 'origin: https://www.example.com' -vv 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FILE_ID_HERE?key=YOUR_API_KEY&alt=media' > out.tmp
```

Comment: Accepted the answer however;
unfortunately that API resource does not support CORS which is required for the intended use. [I originally tried using the webContentLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841275/google-drive-webcontentlink-does-not-support-cors-when-file-is-public) but the returned resource does not support CORS either

Comment: For the URL constructed in the question, can the file name be replaced by the file id? Or must the name/path be used ?

Comment: The Drive API supports CORS, as should downloads. Unless there was a regression, it should work fine. What error do you get?

Comment: The API only returns the access-* headers iff there is is a valid origin header in the request.

Comment: If you look at the pastebin I linked you will see that the request has a valid `Origin` header, its value is `www.example.com`.

Comment: And note I said *valid* origin :) The one in your example isn't fully formed. It's missing the scheme/protocol.