# Google Drive webContentLink does not support CORS when file is public

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, cors

The `webContentLink` is supposed to be a direct link to the file represented by the fileResource.
Let's first ignore the fact that the link will infact always respond with a 302 pointing to a generated `downloadUrl` (which has a very finite life-time).

I understand that the resource pointed to by `webContentLink` uses cookie-based authentication and CORS would pose a security risk, however the documentation explicitly states that no authentication is needed when the file in question is public (obviously).
So for the case where the file is publicly available I do not understand why CORS is not supported.

Is there some security risk associated with this that I fail to realise? Bug? Was it deemed too much work to check the permissions on the file before responding with or without the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

On a side note, using a server-side proxy to fetch the `downloadUrl` pointed to by the 302 location produces a resource that does support CORS.

Comment: Do you need to download the file in the user's side or in the server? if its in the users having the browser make the work with the webContentLink would be enough? If you want to do something specific with the file and if your app is already using the api (i guess thats how you got that url) you can use the DownloadUrl (instead of the webContentLink) to make an authenticated get request (yes even if the file is public the request has to be authenticated) to get the file.

Comment: The link is meant to be used an indefinite amount of time after the link is acquired so fetching the `downloadUrl` instead is no good as it only has a life-time of 8 hours. And no, no authentication is needed when the file pointed to is publicly available, the issue is that the webContentLink does not support CORS so it cannot be accessed in the users browser.

Comment: If the file is public you can call the API methods like files.get without being authenticated, however to call DownloadUrl you do need to be authenticated. I also found that the DownloadUrl you get when using files.get without authentication does not work, If you make the same call being authenticated that URL is different and now it works.  If you need to have the link permanently, as you mention, this Url won't be useful.  Can you explain a little bit more your use case? are you displaying the file in your website? How are you presenting the file info to the user? are you making a link?

Comment: The API is not an option as that always requires OAuth 2.0 authentication. The problem is not implementing the feature, I found a way around the limitation mentioned in the question. The reason for the question is to have a Google employee answer whether the behavior is a bug or intended, but also for people to shed light on a possible security concern that would justify the lack of CORS support.

Comment: Oh ok, that's fine.  If you have the solution, would you be able to post what was your original implementation that gave you the error and how you solve it?  Maybe other users are doing the same thing and can relate to this question or even for testing is better to what are the steps to reproduce he issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Not a solution to the issue posed by the question but using the GDrive hosting feature I was able to work around the limitation of the webContentLink without using a server side proxy.*

`https://googledrive.com/host/shared_folder_id/relative_path`

That link will be a direct link to the file and the resource supports CORS. However this has the limitation that the file's name has to be unique inside its own folder, otherwise it does not work.